# fetching meetings using EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, connection-timeout

I am trying to fetch my calendar meetings which are not canceled but I am getting the error request timed out. I am only running it in my local machine. Please advise.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    service.setTraceEnabled(true);

    service.setUseDefaultCredentials(true);

    service.setTraceEnabled(true);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date startDate = formatter.parse("2015-01-01 00:00:00");
    Date endDate = formatter.parse("2015-01-10 23:59:59");

try{
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));

        CalendarFolder cal = CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
        CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(startDate, startDate);
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults  = cal.findAppointments(calendarView);
        for (Appointment appt : findResults.getItems()) {
        System.out.println("SUBJECT====="+appt.getSubject());
                System.out.println("BODY========"+appt.getBody());
            } 
} catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exceptions.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. Connection timed out: connect caused by Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: Contact your IT department and make sure you are allowed to access the Internet, and to get instructions for doing so with any necessary proxy server.

Comment: Hi I could normally access office 360 in my web browser. I am thinking if this is an firewall issue. But there is nothing wrong with my code right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use default credentials against Office 365, you need to specify them. Remove the line:

```
service.setUseDefaultCredentials(true);
```

And replace it with:

```
string username = "YOUR OFFICE365 EMAIL ADDRESS";
string password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Comment: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceLocalException: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx : Connection error